# missing days in html date input on android huawei

Tags: forms, date, input, phonegap, huawei-mobile-services

At my job we build an app using phonegap. In the registersection we have an input="date" field for the DOB. One of the testusers using testflight reported he couldn't find the 31st of December in 1956 using an huawei phone. So there are day(s) missing in the standard phone datepicker. We tested it at IOS, sony and samsung and can't reproduce it since the whole datepicker looks different.

How is something like this possible? Ever heard of it ?

Here is a picture of the problem:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution?? Maybe hide any of the bottom buttons? thx

Comment: Didn't find anything. To be honest I just left it for wat it was.. If someone had a solution I'll be happy to hear it

Comment: I'll try this plugin https://github.com/alex-pl/cordova-plugin-datetimepicker